# How to test If I am logged into facebook from out of it?

Tags: facebook

I have this facebook login code

```
 $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $my_url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx";


   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
     print_r( $dialog_url);
die();
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name ."<a href=event.php?app_id=".$app_id."&app_secret=".$app_secret."&code=".$code."&access_token=".$response."> Create Event</a>");
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }
```

can I test if I am already connected to facebook website, consider it login to this page ? and no login link is being displayed ?

Answer (score -1):

The question is pretty old but the answer might be helpful to others who finds similar situation. I guess, what you mean to say is to check if you code has successfully logged you to ur facebook account.

Security settings in facebook now has a feature to watch active sessions, gives you the information of when and from where have you logged in to your account. It is under:

```
Account Settings > Security > Active Sessions
```

What you can do is logout of all the sessions with end activity & finally logout of current session, then run the code. Now login via browser (or a different device, but login via browser or a different browser works fine) to see if you have got any more active sessions.

Comment: That does not answer the question. He/she wanted to know how the user’s login status can be checked inside the app to not display the login link if the user is already connected.